# iCal DAV The Server Responded with an Error (HTTP 302) after sleeping

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, ical, caldav

Often when my Macbook Pro Retina has been asleep, I get the following upon waking up:

[image]

It is irritating because I get the bouncy iCal icon in my doc and have to dismiss the error message every time. Anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Several things could cause this, but you could eliminate or reduce the chance by doing any or all of the following:

1. Turn off all networking before sleeping.
2. Reduce the refresh time period for that calendar to avoid it refreshing while the system is waking or getting re-connected with an available network.
3. Quit Calendar before sleeping.
4. Move the calendar to another hosting site (assuming it's not really the Mac that's causing the http error.)